# How can I detect transactions using App Dynamics custom python agent rules?

Tags: monitoring, appdynamics, python-agent

I have the job to monitor an automation platform developed in Python. Currently, we are trying to implement AppDynamics to our monitoring scope. In this perspective, we are facing a issue where our Python Agent does not detect business transactions when we create customized rules (such as Regex) to the Python Agent. How can I solve this problem? Do I need to create a new agent?
Thanks for reading.
Eduardo.

I tried to create various different customization rules. I expect my Python Agent to detect relevant Business Transactions. I also would like to say that I accept sugestions of contents regarding Python Agents in AppDynamics and Transaction detection rules. Thanks!